# Calculation of feasible operations for a certain set of primitive gates

Tags: quantum-gate, gate-synthesis, compiling

Assume we have a set of primitive operations of a quantum processor. How can I determine the set of feasible operations or prove that a certain operation is not feasible?

As an example, one could consider a two-qubit system and say that the set of primitive operations is $$\mathcal{P} = \{U_1(\theta), U_2(\theta), U_3(\theta), U_4(\theta)\}\,,$$

where
$$U_1(\theta) = \exp(-i \theta \cdot X \otimes I)\,,\\ U_2(\theta) = \exp(-i \theta  \cdot  Y \otimes I)
\,,\\ U_3(\theta) = \exp(-i \theta   \cdot  Z \otimes I)\,,\\ U_4(\theta) = \exp(-i \theta   \cdot X \otimes X)\,. $$

Then the question would be, which gates are or are not possible?

Comment: What do you mean by space of feasible operations?

Comment: I mean the set $\mathcal{S}$ of operations that are created by concatenating the primitive gates $\mathcal{P} := \{ U_i \}$, i.e. $\mathcal{S} = \{ \prod_{j \in I} U_j \vert U_j \in \mathcal{P} \forall j \in I \}$.